# Css: Como poner una linea en medio por delante de un td de una tabla html?

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Quiero poner una linea que pase por en medio de los td que tengan la clase "linea". 
Codigo html.

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>ejemplo <div class="linea"></div></td>
                <td>ejemplo</td>
                <td>ejemplo</td>
                <td>ejemplo</td>
                <td>ejemplo</td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td>ejemplo <div class="linea"></div></td>
                <td>ejemplo</td>
                <td>ejemplo</td>
                <td>ejemplo</td>
                <td>ejemplo</td>
            </tr>

    </table>
```

codigo en css

```
.linea:after {
            content: "";
            border-right: 5px solid orange;
            /* margin-right: 60px; */
            z-index: 4;
            float: left;
        }
```

lo que se espera:

la linea debe mostrarse por encima de los td con la clase linea, y en el medio de su porcentaje.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En lo personal evitaría contaminar mi html y lo realizaría con puro `css`.

Los css estarian aplicados solo a primer `td` encontrado en la tabla, lo cual se realiza con: `td:first-child`, posterior a eso utilizar Pseudo-elemento como el `before`, o el `after`, luego una posición en porcentajes que es relativo al `tr`.

Ejemplo.

```css
td:first-child{
position:relative;
}
td:first-child:before{
    content:' ';
    position:absolute;
    border: 2px solid #DEB930;
    left:50%;
    height:96%;
  }
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Col3</td>
    <td>Col4</td>
    <td>Col5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Col1</td>
    <td>Col2</td>
    <td>Col3</td>
    <td>Col4</td>
    <td>Col5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wendi, te dejo un ejemplo, espero que te sirva. Ten en cuenta que el elemento que contenga el div tiene que explicitar una posición relativa.

```css
td {
  position: relative;
}
.linea {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>ejemplo <div class="linea">&nbsp</div></td>
    <td>ejemplo</td>
    <td>ejemplo</td>
    <td>ejemplo</td>
    <td>ejemplo</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ejemplo <div class="linea">&nbsp</div></td>
    <td>ejemplo</td>
    <td>ejemplo</td>
    <td>ejemplo</td>
    <td>ejemplo</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: gracias! porque pones un espacio en blanco? &nbsp al quitarlo desparece la linea. gracias de antemano!